# Getting GuildMember Object with user ID Discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm fairly new to discord.js and Javascript in general. Here I created a simple userinfo command which fetches data of the user and embeds it neatly as you can see below. You can also see that the command requires the author/mod to mention the user to get the result embed but I want to get the same result by member's discord userID.
I tried `message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.member.length(args[0])` but this creates a lot of problems. So basically how do I get to use the same command/code by discord ID.

```js
const moment = require('moment');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')
module.exports = {
description: 'whois',
run: async (client, message, args) => {
    const user = message.mentions.users.first()

        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`**PASSION ISLAND MODERATIONS**`)
            .setColor('#ffc0cb')
            .setThumbnail(user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
            .addField('Username', user.username)
            .addField('User Id', user.id)
            .addField('Account Type', `${user.bot ? 'Bot' : 'Human'}`)
            .addField(`Roles`, `${message.member.roles.cache.size}`)
            .addField(`Joined At`, `${moment.utc(message.member.joinedAt).format('ddd, MMM Do, YYYY, h:mm a')}`)
            .addField(`created At`, `${moment.utc(message.member.createdAt).format('ddd, MMM Do, YYYY, h:mm a')}`)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter(`Requested by ${message.author.username}`)
                 message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })


},
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using

```js
    let user; 
    if(message.mentions.members.first()) {
     user = message.mentions.members.first()
     } else { 
let x = await message.guild.members.cache.get(`${args[0]}`)
user = x.user;
}
```

This would work well with IDs since you can pass a snowflake within the `.get()` function.

Comment: I tried that too doesn't seem to work the whole code crashes because of that! it throws errors within displayavatarurl and pretty much everything

Comment: Could you send the errror?

Comment: It throws this error if i use this i tried it before
.setThumbnail(user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
TypeError: user.displayAvatarURL is not a function

Comment: That's because displayAvatarURL() is a function on User not GuildMember you gotta do ```message.guild.members.cache.get(`${args[0]`).user;``` in that case

Comment: yea i did that doesnt work it throws the same exact error

Comment: Could you screenshot it with the code I mentioned in the last comment and the error.

Comment: [still have errors ](https://i.imgur.com/eqUtL8c.png) can we move to discord if you still wish to help me! Add me 16#7959

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I'm using, can find by user's id, user's name or user's tag.

```js
let user = message.mentions.users.first()||null;
if (!user && args.length > 0) {
   let input = args.join(' ')
   let temp = message.guild.members.cache.get(input) || message.guild.members.cache.find(mem => mem.user.username === input) || mmessage.guild.members.cache.find(mem => mem.user.discriminator === input) || null  
   if (temp) user = temp.user;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be 100% sure you will find the user if he exists in the server can do:

```js
message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.fetch(args[0])
```

Comment: It throws this error if i use this i tried it before
.setThumbnail(user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
TypeError: user.displayAvatarURL is not a function

Comment: I see what your error is can you add this
`if (!user) return message.channel.send("User not found!")`
below where you define user

Comment: How's that a fix hahah user is definitely in the guild @Newbie... maybe

Comment: @JacyHarrington You can still have that check, but yeah, the problem is different and not connected to finding the right user.
displayAvatarURL is a function on User, not GuildMember.
You can do `.setThumbnail(user.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))`

Answer (score -1):

You can try using

```
message.mentions.members.first().then((m) => {
    if (!m) {
        // code
    }
})
// or do this
const member = await message.mentions.members.first();
if (!member) {
    // Code
}
```

or change the `members` to an `users`

as other people have shown you can do that by finding the id in the server like so

```
message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
// This will return null if it doesnt exist so you can do this
const member = await message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
if (!member) {
    // code
}
```

You can combine both of them to check it and be sure that the member exists like this

```
const member = await message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
if (!member) {
    // Code
}
```

hopefully this helped

NOTE : I see that you are using multiple `.addField()` you can use `.addFields()` to optimize your code
like this

```
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .addFields(
        { name: 'name', value: 'the description', inline: true || false },
        { name: 'name', value: 'the description', inline: true || false },
    )
```

Comment: I know that user exists what i'm asking is how do i run the code with user iD like `!whois 736651621584601148`

Comment: @JacyHarrington You can use `message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])` this will work, i added this in the answer aswell

Comment: `.get()` doesn't return a promise you can't use Promise.prototype.then() on it